# Custom style of vue multiselect component

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, multi-select

I have added a vue multiselect component... But I want to customize it with css styles. I already have added some css style but can not do everything I want. Like I want to change the option height, select box height, color of selected items/cross button etc. How can I do those things. What are the class names of those elements and how can I modify those things.

```
<multiselect
                    v-model="value"
                    :options="options"
                    :multiple="true"
                    :close-on-select="false"
                    :clear-on-select="false"
                    :preserve-search="true"
                    :hide-selected="true"
                    :option-height="10"
                    class="min-w-200 w-full mb-2"
                    open-direction="bottom"
                    placeholder="--Select One or More--"
                    :show-labels="false"
                    label="name"
                    track-by="name"
                    :preselect-first="true"
                  >
                    <span
                      slot="selection"
                      slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"
                      class="multiselect__single"
                      v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen"
                      >{{ values.length }} options selected</span
                    >
                  </multiselect>
```

I have created this so far. 
[image]

Here is my css code:

```
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
<style lang="scss" >
.multiselect__tag {
  color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  background-color: rgba(var(--vs-primary), 0.3);
  font-size: 01rem;
}
.multiselect__tag:hover {
  background-color: rgba(var(--vs-warning), 0.3);
}

.multiselect__option--disabled {
  background: purple;
  color: rgba(var(--vs-primary), 1);
  font-style: italic;
}

.multiselect__option--highlight {
  background-color: rgba(var(--vs-primary), 1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

.multiselect__content {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #444;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.multiselect__single {
  height: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 01rem;
  color: #444;
}
.multiselect__tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1.625rem 0.25rem 0.625rem;

  margin-right: 0.625rem;

  line-height: 1;

  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
</style>
```